# Why do most frameworks use margin and not padding on p, h1, h2 etc.?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

Would there be any downside to use padding? Or why everyone seems to go with margin?

Comment: margin prevents elements from sticking to each other which cannot be done by padding..

Comment: It depends on you that where you want space. Outer space, user margin, inside space, use padding. Simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Since i think it is opinion based and depending on the case i try to specify my question more: Why does bootstrap and most websites i tested use margins on p-tags and not paddings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no downside to using either, because `padding` and `margin` are two different things and they are used to achieve different effects. Without a `background` these rules may seem to do visually the same thing, but each add spacing in different places.

**Padding**

`Padding` adds spacing inside the element - between the border of the element and its content. It's used so the `content` of the `element` wouldn't be right next to the edge of the element (or its `border`).

**Margin**

`Margin` adds spacing outside the element itself. It specifies how much space there should be between the element and surrounding elements.

**Other differences:**

- `Margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will always collapse, I.E. two elements with `margin-top:15px` and `maragin-bottom:10px` will have a distance of `15px` from each other. The `padding` rule doesn't care what the `padding` of other elements is and will never collapse.
- `Margins` can also be used to make elements *overlap* by using *negative values*. Negative `padding` isn't valid and won't do anything.
- `Margin` is always *transparent* and can't have a `background`. The `background` is, however, painted on the `padding` (unless you use the `background-origin: content-box` rule, which paints the background only inside the element's content).
- `Margin` can be used to center elements using the value `auto` on both `margin-left` and `margin-right`. `Padding` can't be `auto`.

[image]

Run the snippet below to see the difference in action:

```css
div{
  background: #B4D455;
  width: 100px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2n){
  background: #D4B055;  
}

.padding{
  padding: 10px;  
}

.margin{
  margin: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<h3>None</h3>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>

<h3>padding:10px;</h3>
<div class="padding">content</div>
<div class="padding">content</div>
<div class="padding">content</div>

<h3>margin:10px;</h3>
<div class="margin">content</div>
<div class="margin">content</div>
<div class="margin">content</div>

<h3>margin:10px; and padding:10px;</h3>
<div class="padding margin">content</div>
<div class="padding margin">content</div>
<div class="padding margin">content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out that the main difference for me is that margins do collapse in some cases and padding not. I think for some p-tags is nicer if the spaces in between do collapse so you don't have big gaps in your texts.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. Don't use `padding` for putting space between elements. I improved my answer to include other differences the two rules have.

Comment: Thank you, like this my questions is answered.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the example from above there is one difference more. Margin can collapse in some cases and padding does not. So it can look different even without background-colors, since the total space between two elements of the same kind can be different.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X13O.png)

Comment: `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` collapse every time, not in "some cases".